# Building dynamic DataGrid with Binded ColumHeaders

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm building a `DataGrid` dynamically, the columns are showed as I need, but my column headers don't show anything.

I was trying to set the `HeaderTemplate` for each column but my final `DataGrid` shows empty headers.

My `DataGrid` generator:

```
private void ImportarView_ColumnsToMapChanged(object sender, ColumnsToMapChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ImportColumns = e.Columns;
    Importar source = ((Importar)GrdMain.DataContext);
    DGrdDatosImportar.Columns.Clear();

    foreach (ColumnParms columnparms in ImportColumns)
    {
        string ColName = $"Col{columnparms.ColumnName}";
        ImportColumn Col = new ImportColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding($"{columnparms.ColumnName}.DisplayValue"),
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            ColParms = columnparms
        };
        Col.SetNameScope(ColName,this);

        var MyTb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        //Binding txtBind = new Binding($"ElementName={ColName},Path=ColParms.ColumnName");
        Binding txtBind = new Binding("TextProperty")
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, Col.GetType(), 1),
            Path = new PropertyPath(Col.ColParms.ColumnName)                   
        };
        MyTb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, txtBind);
        MyTb.SetValue(TextBox.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
        DataTemplate MyHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = MyTb };
        Col.HeaderTemplate = MyHeaderTemplate;

        Col.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        DGrdDatosImportar.Columns.Add(Col);
    }
}
```

My Column:

```
public class ImportColumn : DataGridTextColumn 
{
    #region Column Parms
    public ColumnParms ColParms
    {
        get { return (ColumnParms)GetValue(ColParmsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColParmsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColParmsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ColParms", typeof(ColumnParms), typeof(ImportColumn));
    #endregion

    private NameScope ColumnScope = new NameScope();

    public void SetNameScope(string name,object scope)
    {
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this,ColumnScope);
        ColumnScope.RegisterName(name, scope);
    }
}
```

This is my final DataGrid with data but without headers:
[image]

What is the way to set the Header programmatically?

NOTE: My Column class already has a reference to its own binding source.

Comment: Which property value are you intending to display in the header?

Comment: @mm8 I need to Show two TextBlock's  binding Text to an object property into my column. For simplicity in question's code just one Textbox for now. But really I want a Grid with two rows and at each row one TextBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve my problem by combining two properties of my header

```
Header =  columnparms
```

Header Act as DataConext for my ColumnHeader then, set HeaderTemplate with my textbox

```
    private void ImportarView_ColumnsToMapChanged(object sender, ColumnsToMapChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImportColumns = e.Columns;
        Importar source = ((Importar)GrdMain.DataContext);
        DGrdDatosImportar.Columns.Clear();

        foreach (ColumnParms columnparms in ImportColumns)
        {
            #region Crear la columna
            ImportColumn Col = new ImportColumn()
            {
                Header = columnparms,
                Binding = new Binding($"{columnparms.ColumnName}.DisplayValue"),
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                ColParms = columnparms
            };
            #endregion

            #region Text block Nombre de la columna
            Binding txtBind = new Binding("TextProperty") { Path = new PropertyPath("DisplayString", null) };
            var MyTb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            MyTb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, txtBind);
            #endregion

            Col.HeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = MyTb };

            DGrdDatosImportar.Columns.Add(Col);
        }
    }
```